# Grails1.4M1 + GAE + gorm-jpa don't work

Tags: google-app-engine, grails, grails-plugin, gae-eclipse-plugin

any idea?

1. how to fix it?
2. where to add grails compile arg ?

ERROR STACK:

> Welcome to Grails 1.4.0.M1 -
>   http://grails.org/ Licensed under
>   Apache Standard License 2.0 Grails
>   home is set to: D:\Tool\Grails\
>
> Base Directory:
>   D:\Workspace\Git\TzLib\GAE\tz-app
>   WARNING: Configurational method
>   [compile] in
>   grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy
>   doesn't exist. Ignoring.. WARNING:
>   Configurational method [compile] in
>   grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy
>   doesn't exist. Ignoring.. WARNING:
>   Configurational method [runtime] in
>   grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy
>   doesn't exist. Ignoring.. WARNING:
>   Configurational method [runtime] in
>   grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy
>   doesn't exist. Ignoring.. Running
>   script RunApp.groovy Environment set
>   to development   [groovyc] Compiling
>   11 source files to
>   D:\Workspace\Git\TzLib\GAE\tz-app\web-app\WEB-INF\classes
>   [groovyc]
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed:   [groovyc] Compile
>   error during compilation with javac.
>   [groovyc]
>   D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\tz-app\plugins\gorm-jpa-0.7.1\src\java\org\grails\jpa\domain\JpaGrailsDomainClass.java:46:
>   org.grails.jpa.domain.JpaGrailsDomainClass
>   不是抽象的，并且未覆盖
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsDomainClass
>   中的抽象方法
>   getPersistentProperty(java.lang.String)
>   [groovyc] public class
>   JpaGrailsDomainClass extends
>   AbstractGrailsClass implements
>   GrailsDomainClass {   [groovyc]
>   ^   [groovyc]
>   注意：D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\tz-app\plugins\gorm-jpa-0.7.1\src\java\org\grails\jpa\domain\JpaGrailsDomainClass.java
>   使用或覆盖了已过时的 API。   [groovyc]
>   注意：要了解详细信息，请使用 -Xlint:deprecation
>   重新编译。   [groovyc]
>   注意：D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\tz-app\plugins\gorm-jpa-0.7.1\src\java\org\grails\jpa\domain\JpaGrailsDomainClass.java
>   使用了未经检查或不安全的操作。   [groovyc]
>   注意：要了解详细信息，请使用 -Xlint:unchecked 重新编译。 
>   [groovyc] 1 错误   [groovyc]
>   [groovyc]    [groovyc] 1 error :
>   Compilation Failed    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:918)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:606)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at
>   _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure7.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:70)
>     at
>   _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3_closure7.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
>     at
>   _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:67)
>     at
>   java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)   at
>   _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:46)
>     at
>   java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)   at
>   _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:85)
>     at
>   _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy)
>     at
>   _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:84)
>     at
>   java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)   at
>   RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:28)     at
>   java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)   at
>   java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)   at
>   java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: Compile error during
>   compilation with javac.
>   D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\tz-app\plugins\gorm-jpa-0.7.1\src\java\org\grails\jpa\domain\JpaGrailsDomainClass.java:46:
>   org.grails.jpa.domain.JpaGrailsDomainClass
>   不是抽象的，并且未覆盖
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsDomainClass
>   中的抽象方法
>   getPersistentProperty(java.lang.String)
>   public class JpaGrailsDomainClass
>   extends AbstractGrailsClass implements
>   GrailsDomainClass {
>          ^ 注意：D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\tz-app\plugins\gorm-jpa-0.7.1\src\java\org\grails\jpa\domain\JpaGrailsDomainClass.java
>   使用或覆盖了已过时的 API。 注意：要了解详细信息，请使用
>   -Xlint:deprecation 重新编译。 注意：D:\TZProfile.grails\1.4.0.M1\projects\tz-app\plugins\gorm-jpa-0.7.1\src\java\org\grails\jpa\domain\JpaGrailsDomainClass.java
>   使用了未经检查或不安全的操作。 注意：要了解详细信息，请使用
>   -Xlint:unchecked 重新编译。 1 错误
>
> 1 error
>
> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:302)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavacJavaCompiler.addJavacError(JavacJavaCompiler.java:92)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavacJavaCompiler.compile(JavacJavaCompiler.java:71)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavaAwareCompilationUnit.gotoPhase(JavaAwareCompilationUnit.java:92)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:507)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:476)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:67)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:180)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:903)
>     ... 17 more Compilation error:
>   Compilation Failed

Comment: Did you tried `grails clean` before compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the plugin. As the error message says, `JpaGrailsDomainClass` doesn't implement the method `GrailsDomainClassProperty getPersistentProperty(String name)` - this was added in 1.4 to the `GrailsDomainClass` interface.

You should report the bug at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPAPPENGINE